# Internet Explorer adding random height

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Can someone explain to me where this styling in internet explorer is coming from? I'm not new to css and I've never come accross this issue. Absolutely no idea where IE is getting that height from. 
Of course I can just add a max-height but I'd still like to understand why it's happening.

[image: Internet explorer is the worst]

Answer (score 0):

All browser have at least 3 css stylesheets. The First is from the browser it self, one from the user browser setting (you can add a custom css for some special reason on all site that this browser get) and all other stylesheets are yours, that can be an inline, extern or js manipulated style.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it's none of my stylesheets. There are also no inline styles modifying this element and internet explorer is not giving me any feedback that it is either. It obviously is though as the issue doesn't appear on any other browser. It's some really fun ghost styling.

Comment: It's probably the user-agent style (IE default style). Try to use some css normalize files.

Comment: Look at this link, there are the default css rules for Internet Explorer: http://www.iecss.com/